# How to use bufio.ScanWords

Tags: go

How do I use `bufio.ScanWords` and `bufio.ScanLines` functions to count words and lines?

I tried:

```
fmt.Println(bufio.ScanWords([]byte("Good day everyone"), false))
```

Prints:

```
5 [103 111 111 100] <nil>
```

Not sure what that means?

Comment: The `Scan*` functions of `bufio` are not meant to be invoked directly. They are instead designed for use as arguments to [`bufio.Scanner.Split`](https://godoc.org/bufio#Scanner.Split).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To count words:

```
input := "Spicy jalapeno pastrami ut ham turducken.\n Lorem sed ullamco, leberkas sint short loin strip steak ut shoulder shankle porchetta venison prosciutto turducken swine.\n Deserunt kevin frankfurter tongue aliqua incididunt tri-tip shank nostrud.\n"
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(input))
// Set the split function for the scanning operation.
scanner.Split(bufio.ScanWords)
// Count the words.
count := 0
for scanner.Scan() {
    count++
}
if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "reading input:", err)
}
fmt.Printf("%d\n", count)
```

To count lines:

```
input := "Spicy jalapeno pastrami ut ham turducken.\n Lorem sed ullamco, leberkas sint short loin strip steak ut shoulder shankle porchetta venison prosciutto turducken swine.\n Deserunt kevin frankfurter tongue aliqua incididunt tri-tip shank nostrud.\n"

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(input))
// Set the split function for the scanning operation.
scanner.Split(bufio.ScanLines)
// Count the lines.
count := 0
for scanner.Scan() {
    count++
}
if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "reading input:", err)
}
fmt.Printf("%d\n", count)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an exercise in book The Go Programming Language Exercise 7.1

This is an extension of [@repler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7202914/replper) solution:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type byteCounter int
type wordCounter int
type lineCounter int

func main() {
    var c byteCounter
    c.Write([]byte("Hello This is a line"))
    fmt.Println("Byte Counter ", c)

    var w wordCounter
    w.Write([]byte("Hello This is a line"))
    fmt.Println("Word Counter ", w)

    var l lineCounter
    l.Write([]byte("Hello \nThis \n is \na line\n.\n.\n"))
    fmt.Println("Length ", l)

}

func (c *byteCounter) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    *c += byteCounter(len(p))
    return len(p), nil
}

func (w *wordCounter) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    count := retCount(p, bufio.ScanWords)
    *w += wordCounter(count)
    return count, nil
}

func (l *lineCounter) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    count := retCount(p, bufio.ScanLines)
    *l += lineCounter(count)
    return count, nil
}

func retCount(p []byte, fn bufio.SplitFunc) (count int) {
    s := string(p)
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(s))
    scanner.Split(fn)
    count = 0
    for scanner.Scan() {
        count++
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "reading input:", err)
    }
    return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an exercise in book *The Go Programming Language* Exercise 7.1

This is my solution:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
)

// WordCounter count words
type WordCounter int

// LineCounter count Lines
type LineCounter int

type scanFunc func(p []byte, EOF bool) (advance int, token []byte, err error)

func scanBytes(p []byte, fn scanFunc) (cnt int) {
    for true {
        advance, token, _ := fn(p, true)
        if len(token) == 0 {
            break
        }
        p = p[advance:]
        cnt++
    }
    return cnt
}

func (c *WordCounter) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    cnt := scanBytes(p, bufio.ScanWords)
    *c += WordCounter(cnt)
    return cnt, nil
}

func (c WordCounter) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("contains %d words", c)
}

func (c *LineCounter) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    cnt := scanBytes(p, bufio.ScanLines)
    *c += LineCounter(cnt)
    return cnt, nil
}

func (c LineCounter) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("contains %d lines", c)
}

func main() {
    var c WordCounter
    fmt.Println(c)

    fmt.Fprintf(&c, "This is an sentence.")
    fmt.Println(c)

    c = 0
    fmt.Fprintf(&c, "This")
    fmt.Println(c)

    var l LineCounter
    fmt.Println(l)

    fmt.Fprintf(&l, `This is another
line`)
    fmt.Println(l)

    l = 0
    fmt.Fprintf(&l, "This is another\nline")
    fmt.Println(l)

    fmt.Fprintf(&l, "This is one line")
    fmt.Println(l)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`bufio.ScanWords`](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#ScanWords) and [`bufio.ScanLines`](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#ScanLines) (as well as [`bufio.ScanBytes`](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#ScanBytes) and [`bufio.ScanRunes`](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#ScanRunes)) are *split functions*: they provide a `bufio.Scanner` with **the strategy to *tokenize* its input data** – how the process of scanning should split the data. The split function for a `bufio.Scanner` is `bufio.ScanLines` by default but can be changed through the method [`bufio.Scanner.Split`](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Scanner.Split).

These split functions are of type [`SplitFunc`](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#SplitFunc):

```
type SplitFunc func(data []byte, atEOF bool) (advance int, token []byte, err error)
```

Usually, you won't need to call any of these functions directly; instead, `bufio.Scanner` will. However, you might need to create your own split function for implementing a custom tokenization strategy. So, let's have a look at its parameters:

- `data`: remaining data not processed yet.
- `atEOF`: whether or not the caller has reached EOF and therefore has no more new data to provide in the next call.
- `advance`: number of **bytes** the caller must advance the input data for the next call.
- `token`: the token to return to the caller as a result of the splitting performed.

To gain further understanding, let's see [`bufio.ScanBytes`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.4:src/bufio/scan.go;l=289) implementation:

```
func ScanBytes(data []byte, atEOF bool) (advance int, token []byte, err error) {
    if atEOF && len(data) == 0 {
        return 0, nil, nil
    }
    return 1, data[0:1], nil
}
```

As long as `data` isn't empty, it returns a token byte to the caller (`data[0:1]`) and tells the caller to advance the input data by one byte.

Answer (score 0):

To explain the output of bufio.ScanWords:

- The first return value represents the length of bytes in current
  word(including leading and trailing spaces), say **num_bytes**, which helps to
  move to the beginning of the next word, by moving to **current_index +
  num_bytes** index.
- The second return value represents the bytes of the word(with
  any leading and trailing spaces removed).
- And the third one represents the error.

Here is a simple program to count the words, using these information:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var ar []byte = []byte("hello there,       how are ya.. \n And bye")

    num_words := 0

    start := 0
    for num, array, b := bufio.ScanWords(ar[start:], true); ; num, array, b = bufio.ScanWords(ar[start:], true) {
        if b != nil {
            break
        }
        num_words++

        for _, char := range array {
            fmt.Printf("%c", char)
        }
        fmt.Println(" ")

        start += num
        if start >= len(ar) {
            break
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("The number of words is ", num_words)

}
```

And here is the corresponding output:
[Output for above's code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptrIh.png)
The second argument seems to specify whether to stop at EOF, here is an output with the second argument set to false.
[Output with the second argument set to false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irZwP.png)
As you can see, the loop doesn't stop, unless we use num>0 as the condition in the for loop.

I hope this was helpful.